# Visual Studio Express 2013 behind proxy

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2013

I've just downloaded and installed visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop.

I'm working behind a proxy with username/password authentication and I don't find how to register the product (witch is now active for 14 days).

Each time : 407 - Proxy Authentication Required

I tried editing the WDExpress.exe.config to add in the  section

```
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://x.x.x.x:8080"
        bypassonlocal="true"
        />
```

but it's nor working.

Comment: Could you activate by telephone instead? (Not sure if this is an option with VS).

Comment: It seems it's not possible with vse 2013.  Only online registration.

Comment: Wait... Express? That's free!

Comment: Yes it's free but you have to register to have your free licence (like avast) !

Comment: Same problem. My Express expired and no news from MS regarding a fix for it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your visual studio folder, search for the devenv.exe.config file, search for `<system.net>` tag and replace it with the following:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for Visual Studio 2017 but can be adapted to similar errors and applications. Can be used as a general method to Visual Studio proxy errors, just changing processes and locations. 
UPDATE: It works for Visual Studio 2015 too. You must configure one process only.

Follow the next steps:

1. **Create a dll** with authentication data.
2. **Copy the dll** to directory of each process
3. **Configure** Visual Studio ".exe.config" **XML file for each process** to use the dll created.
   4.(optional) Try Visual Studio when **monitoring with Fiddler**.

---

1. You can use a lightweight IDE like **SharpDevelop** to create the dll.
   In ShareDevelop, click in *File->New->Solution* and select the category *C#/Windows Application/windows User Control Library*. Name the application as *AuthProxy*.
   Create one class named *AuthProxyModule.cs* and put this code inside:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Net;

   namespace AuthProxy

   {
       public class AuthProxyModule : IWebProxy
       {

           ICredentials crendential = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

               public ICredentials Credentials    
               {    
                   get
                   {
                       return crendential;
                   }
                   set
               {
                   crendential = value;
               }
           }

           public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
           {
               return new Uri("http://proxy:8080", UriKind.Absolute);
           }

           public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
           {
               return host.IsLoopback;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   In *"USERNAME"* and *"PASSWORD"* you should set with the correct values for you. Also you should configure the right URI (in the example, *proxy:8080*)
   Build the solution and you can get the AuthProxy.dll in the solution/bin/Debug folder. 
   This step is based on this [site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rido/2010/05/06/how-to-connect-to-tfs-through-authenticated-web-proxy/).
2. Copy the Authproxy.dll file to this directories:

   - (2017, 2015) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
   - (2017 only) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService
   - (2017 only) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.Settings
   - (2017 only) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86
3. Then Add the code below between  and  tags:

   ```
   <system.net>
     <defaultProxy>
       <module type="AuthProxy.AuthProxyModule, AuthProxy"/>
     </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
   ```

   to this XML config files in the directories from the step 2 **respectively**:

   - devenv.exe.config (2015, 2017)
   - Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.dll.config (2017)
   - Microsoft.Developer.Settings.dll.config (2017)
   - ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe.config (2017)
4. Monitoring with Fiddler. 
   In Fiddler, the column *Process* shows *devenv* or *servicehub.identityhub* or *servicehub.settingshost*. The process which generates the request.

   The column *Result* shows *407* when an error occurred. The *200* is shown when it is working. The connections HTTP/1.1 will return *407*. The connections HTTP/1.0 should return *200*. If not, you must check the config file associated to the process.

   In the *Inspectors* tab, click on *Auth* view for the request and *Headers* view for the response. It is a simple way to understand what it is happens.

Notes: Keep in mind that if you **upgrade Visual Studio**, *devenv.exe.config* file is modified and `<system.net>` is automatically changed by the installer to:

```
    <system.net>
      <settings> 
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
      </settings>
    </system.net>
```

You should reconfigure the processes.

This solution seems complicated but it works for me and allow me understanding and monitoring what is it happens.