# Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web update license issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web 30 days ago. I did not have access to this machine in the last two weeks and now the trail has expired. If i understand correctly you just need to sign in to your Visual Studio account from the application to extend this license. But the only thing i have access to is the screen Visual Studio shows me when starting the application.

This screen says:

License: 30 day trial (for evaluation purposes only)

This license has expired.
You are not able to update your license in this application.

I am behind a proxy but changed the VWDExpress config file as suggested as answer to other questions regarding extending the license behind a proxy. I have tried repairing Visual Studio and tried reinstalling it. Both did not change anything. I am wondering if anyone could help me what to try next.

Comment: You need access to internet to get the key (well key can activated offline if you have them). If you don't have internet you need to obtain it from Microsoft from another computer which is connected to internet.

Comment: After your comment i double checked and it seems i did not successfully navigate the proxy after all. Even though Visual Studio did not mention it anymore. After some tinkering in the config file it is working now. Thanks for your quick comment Gupta.

Comment: You can try to with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350610/3816639.